# How to do colour formatting in drilldown pivot report

Tags: reporting-services

I have made a Drill down report in SSRS 2008 with one parent group and 4 child group each group field aggregates value under a pivot column.I have to do conditional formatting to change the background color of the pivot field if the particular aggregate value exceeds the input value on each drilldown field.

I have tried multiple expression With 'IIF' and 'SWITCH' condition to change the background color in pivot field in each drill down field.

```
=switch(
 Fields!CIRCLE.Value,"DataSet1" AND (fields!TOTAL.Value>30000,"DataSet1"),"Red",

       (Fields!ZONE.Value,"DataSet1" AND (fields!TOTAL.Value>100,"DataSet1"),"Red",

        (Fields!CLUSTER.Value,"DataSet1" AND (fields!TOTAL.Value>5000,"DataSet1"),"Red",

        (Fields!NODE.Value,"DataSet1" AND (fields!TOTAL.Value>3000,"DataSet1"),"Red","White"
))))
```

I want the Pivot field Hour with sum as aggregates to turn red on circle level zone level,cluster level and node level like example if the Sum field under pivot column is 700 in 3rd hour and it exceeds 300 then the value at 3rd hour should turn red on circle level.

Comment: Could you post an example of the report with data to help clarify what it is you actually need help with?

Comment: Data Set in the SSRS  report  are Circle,Zone,Cluster,Node,Date,Hour,Total,Parent group Date,Child group Circle ,Zone,Cluster,Node,Pivot Field Hour(0-23) aggregate pivot field sum(total).There is row field and column field Total which calculates  Total sum of all the drilldown fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
=switch( Fields!CIRCLE.Value > 30000 AND Fields!TOTAL.Value >30000,"Red",
         Fields!ZONE.Value> 100 AND Fields!TOTAL.Value > 100,"Red",
         Fields!CLUSTER.Value > 5000 AND Fields!TOTAL.Value > 5000,"Red",
         Fields!NODE.Value > 3000 AND Fields!TOTAL.Value > 3000 ,"Red")
```

Comment: After applying the above expression i am encountering a warning,'[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Textbox30_InAutoSubtotal1’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.
Preview complete -- 0 errors, 1 warnings
'

Comment: its possible the data value within CIRCLE, ZONE, CLUSTER or NODE may not be an "Integer" ?

Comment: It is always an Integer value.

Answer (score 1):

[image]@Aditi Singh we are on the correct track, have a look at images below, let me know your thoughts:

[image]

Comment: Indeed we are but here the expression is for all the circles in a particular hour i just want vice-versa of it i want for a single circle along side all the hours.

Comment: And i also there has to be only four Criteria ie for Circle,Zone,Cluster,Node and all the values exceeding the criteria for particular Circle in 24 hours span should be formatted same will be the case for zone,cluster and node.

Comment: for example in the above screenshot for circle AR value in 1st hour should also be formatted as it is greater than 300 which is the criteria for the overall circle.

Comment: in the example i have shown expression for hour column 3 or 4, it would just be a matter of editing the expression to include hour column 1

Comment: But i want Total along row to get formatted not along columns.

Comment: If you want total highlighted colours then change the expression to: =SWITCH(Fields!HOUR1.Value = "3" AND sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) >= "300", "red",Fields!HOUR1.Value = "4" AND sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) >= "400", "ORANGE") and apply this to the total column only

Comment: i want the values to be compared along Rows for each group field not along column.

Comment: @AditiSingh could post an example of what you are expecting

Comment: have you got any solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

@SuperSimmer44 Below is the link image for the desried Output- 
[Drilldown Report sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NgpB.png)Scenario: Circle>4000(Red), Zone>3000(Red), Cluster>500(Red)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method (you will need to extend to hour value 10+):

```
=switch(Fields!HOUR1.Value = "1" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "100", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "2" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "200", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "3" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "300", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "4" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "400", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "5" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "500", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "6" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "600", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "7" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "700", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "8" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "800", "RED",
        Fields!HOUR1.Value = "9" and Fields!TOTAL.Value >= "900", "RED",
        )
```

Comment: It means i'll extend it for 24 hours ie(0-23)

Comment: yes extend for 24 hours, I am a little unsure of the field names you may need to amend these and also the criteria for each switch value.....

Comment: I guess it wont give me the desired outcome as there is a fixed criteria for all the fields like at circle level if the pivot column value exceeds by 300 it should turn all the values red exceeding 300 in 0-23 hours.